# \chaptermark, \tableofcontents and unnumbered chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr

I have two questions about this code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[inner=3cm, outer=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyheadoffset[LE,RO]{0pt}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\large\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\large\textit{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
    \cfoot{{- \thepage\ -}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.4pt}
 }
 \fancypagestyle{plain}{% 
    \fancyhf{} 
    \fancyfoot[C]{{- \thepage\ -}}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
 }
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{\thechapter.\ #1}}

 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \mainmatter
 \pagestyle{mystyle}

 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \lipsum[1-20]
 \chapter*{Conclusion}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
 \lipsum[1-20]
 \end{document}
```

1. Why `\chaptermark` does not affect headers if `\tableofcontents` is not present?
2. Is there a way to make `fancyhdr` able to recognise a `\chapter*` automatically and prin in both headers with the chapter title only (without the number)? (Adding `\markboth{Conclusion}{Conclusion}` after the `\addcontentsline` will fix it manually)

Comment: Problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: see below how to keep the original `\chapter*` code.

1. Why `\chaptermark` does not affect headers if `\tableofcontents` is not present?

I don't see that. If I comment out `\tableofcontents` I do still get the '*1. First Chapter*' heading.

2. Is there a way to make fancyhdr able to recognise a `\chapter*` automatically?

Fancyhdr doesn't mangle `\chapter` commands and the like. It just uses what their mark command supply.

But you could define your own command, like

```
\newcommand\chapterstar[1]{\chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{#1}}
. . . 
 \chapterstar{Conclusion}
```

**EDIT (addition)**

Actually with `xparse` you can easily redefine `\chapter*` to include the `\markboth` command.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\origchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand \chapter { s O{#3} m }
{
  \IfBooleanTF {#1}
  { \origchapter*{#3}\markboth {#3} {#3} }
  { \origchapter [#2] {#3} }
}
```